# Laravel : failed to run development server

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue while trying to start laravel development server :

```
> php --version
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2021 14:06:15) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

> composer global require laravel/installer

> laravel new PhpApp

> cd PhpApp

> php artisan serve
```

And I get :

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpApp/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpApp\artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpApp/vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpApp\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: have you run `composer install`?

Comment: It appears there is a file that cannot be loaded. Have you confirmed the file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @James Clark Developer.

Here is the full output :

```
    C:\Users\Théo\Code>laravel new PhpTest

_                               _
| |                             | |
| |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
| |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
| |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
|______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|

    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./PhpTest"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.15)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.15): Extracting archive
    Created project in C:\Users\Théo\Code/PhpTest
    > @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

C:\Users\Théo\Code>cd PhpTest

C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpTest>composer install
No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

C:\Users\Théo\Code\PhpTest>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

EDIT :

After many searches, I found the solution : I had to edit my php.ini file in C:\php\php.ini

And remove the ";" for "extension=fileinfo"